# How to position facebook popup window?

Tags: facebook

I'm using the facebook button below

```
<fb:login-button perms='email, user_photos, user_birthday, user_online_presence'
        autologoutlink='true'></fb:login-button>
```

Each time I click it its opening popup window floated to the right. How to set it to center?

I tried on clean page without any styles tried in different browsers and all the time just login window floated right

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
   function popupFB() {

     // Modify window settings here 
     var width = 400;
     var height = 400;
     var left = parseInt((screen.availWidth/2) - (width/2));
     var top = parseInt((screen.availHeight/2) - (height/2));
     var windowFeatures = "width=" + width + ",height=" + height + ",status,resizable,left=" + left + ",top=" + top + "screenX=" + left + ",screenY=" + top;


     //redirect_uri -where to redirect after the user approves your app 
     // scope - permissions separated by comma - like perms in the fb:login-button
     // APP_ID - your app id

     login_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=APP_ID&scope=publish_stream&redirect_uri=window.location'; 

     window.open(login_url, "mywindow", windowFeatures);

   }
```

You have to add a custom login button that triggers this function.